# Ключевое слово const в возвращаемом значении

Tags: c++

MSVC позволяет декларировать тип возвращаемого значения функции c использованием ключевого слова `const`. Учитывая, что такой реализации не предусмотрено в документации MS C++ (возможно в синтаксисе она и присутствует, но я еще не на той стадии, чтобы понимать что в этой графе описывается), ожидается, что `const` в данном случае будет реализовывать функционал `constexpr`.

```cpp
const int F() {
  int value;
  std::cin >> value;
  return value;
}
```

Однако и вышеупомянутый написанный код успешно компилируется. Что происходит в данном примере? Кажется, использование const в данном примере бесполезно, хоть IDE и видит идентификатор F как const int.

Comment: Да ничего не происходит. Возвращается константное значение типа `int`, но поскольку все, что вы с ним можете сделать - просто его куда-то скопировать, то это `const` просто особого смысла не имеет. И уж конечно const и constexpr — это две ну очень большие  разницы...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Стандарт](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#type-2) говорит, что prvalue (т.е., грубо говоря, временные объекты), тип которых - не класс и не массив, автоматически теряют `const` и `volatile`. Поэтому в вашем случае `const` ничего не делает.

А если возвращать из функции класс, то `const` вреден, потому что константный временный объект нельзя переместить, и он вместо этого будет втихую копироваться.

---

> ожидается, что const в данном случае будет реализовывать функционал constexpr

Нет, это так не работает.

> Однако и вышеупомянутый написанный код успешно компилируется.

А он даже с `constexpr` теперь компилируется, потому что в С++23 разрешили навешивать `constexpr` на почти любые функции. Если он неприменим, то просто тихо игнорируется.